# Problem with calculations in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, calculation

I have two tables: bill and product. In table product there is an attribute price of product and in table bill there are attributes quantity and total price. So I need to calculate the attribute total price by multiplicating attributes price from product and quantity from bill. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I, somehow, doubt that those tables contain only columns you mentioned. Both of them lack in some kind of an `ID` which would make joining possible. Otherwise, it just wouldn't make sense.

For example (along with some sample data):

```
SQL> create table product (product_id number, price number);

Table created.

SQL> create table bill    (product_id number, quantity number, total_price number);

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into product (product_id, price)    values (1, 100)
  3    into product (product_id, price)    values (2, 200)
  4    into bill    (product_id, quantity) values (1, 5)
  5  select * from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from product;

PRODUCT_ID      PRICE
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2        200

SQL> select * from bill;

PRODUCT_ID   QUANTITY TOTAL_PRICE
---------- ---------- -----------
         1          5

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

In order to set `total_price` column value, you can use `UPDATE`

```
SQL> update bill b set
  2    b.total_price = (select b.quantity * p.price
  3                     from product p
  4                     where p.product_id = b.product_id
  5                    );

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From bill;

PRODUCT_ID   QUANTITY TOTAL_PRICE
---------- ---------- -----------
         1          5         500

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.
```

or `MERGE`:

```
SQL> merge into bill b
  2    using (select p.product_id, p.price
  3           from product p
  4          ) x
  5    on (b.product_id = x.product_id)
  6  when matched then update set b.total_price = b.quantity * x.price;

1 row merged.

SQL> select * From bill;

PRODUCT_ID   QUANTITY TOTAL_PRICE
---------- ---------- -----------
         1          5         500
```

As you tagged the question with an Apex tag, it is unclear what you actually have. What kind of a page is it? If it is one of reports (classic or interactive), you could join tables on `product_id` as

```
SQL> select b.product_id, b.quantity, p.price, b.quantity * p.price as total_price
  2  from product p join bill b on b.product_id = p.product_id;

PRODUCT_ID   QUANTITY      PRICE TOTAL_PRICE
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1          5        100         500
```

If it is a form page, then use a dynamic action which *sets value* when `P1_PRICE` and/or `P1_QUANTITY` are changed; suppose that it is page 1, then you'd set `P1_TOTAL_PRICE` to

```
:P1_PRICE * :P1_QUANTITY
```

Basically, quite a few options. The one you'll use depends on what you really have.